# Debug client code in Android/iPad/iPhone

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, meteor, weinre

I have been trying to find a way to debug client code in mobile devices browser.
For Android, I have located this:

https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/debugging

For iPad/iPhone, weinre seem promising but I have not been able to get it to work:

http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Home.html

Has anyone been able to get weinre working with Meteor?

Answer (score 0):

I've use [Adobe Edge Inspect](http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/) with a little success.  I think it's pretty much the same thing as Weinre (It uses Weinre at least).  Maybe give it a try and see if you have better luck.